# Плагин 18+ на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Существует ли плагин, который при заходе пользователя на сайт, просил бы подтверждения, что ему есть 18 лет?

Comment: Да любой плагин всплывающих окон.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие плагины. В них есть куча настроек, можно применять плагины на весь сайт или отдельный контент, разные возрастные пороги на конкретный контент и так далее. То, что вам нужно:

Age Gate — https://wordpress.org/plugins/age-gate/

Content Warning — https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-warning-v2/